# JasperReports Summary moves to next page

Tags: jasper-reports

I had a report with the following measures and the report got generated in single page with frame1 and frame2 inside `summary`.

```
pageHeight="810" topMargin="5" bottomMargin="5"
title band => height="260"
detail band => height="290"
summary band => height="231"
    frame1 => height="105"
    frame2 => height="84"
```

I appended the third frame into `summary` retaining same heights for all other parts and increased  `pageHeight` as below. Now the entire `summary` part is moved to the next page, for the same number of `detail` table dataset record rows.

I require frame1 and frame2 to be on the first page, frame3 on second page. I tried replacing `Stretch` splitType with `Prevent` on summary but it didn't solve the issue.

```
pageHeight="1210" topMargin="5" bottomMargin="5"
title band => height="260"
detail band => height="290"
summary band => height="681"
    frame1 => height="105"
    frame2 => height="84"
    frame3 => height="250"
```